# The door to the room of the petrified woman is closed! How can I open it?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I play *Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the Fist Sin* and was already in that room with the petrified woman, but after some story progression, I wanted to go to this area again but the door is closed.

[image: Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the Fist Sin Screenshot]

How can I open this door shown in my screenshot? Any clues? I think I didn't use the 'Fragrant Branch of Yore' in the inside before.

Comment: Pull the lever? Or warp to the bonfire inside? IIRC that door closes when the door on the other side is opened.

Comment: I don't have any bonefires inside. What lever?

Comment: I might be wrong about this but isn't there a lever on the wall to the right of the door? Not _technically_ a lever I suppose but one of those things that you pull out of the wall.

Comment: No, nothing there. BUT after logging out and restarting the game the door was opened again. The woman is still petrified. I was afraid I would have to start all over again with a new character.

Comment: Oh, I was confused. I thought you had already un-petrified her. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar As soon as you open the door, and the area is reloaded, Benhart disappears from that location.

Comment: @Z3noN can I ask exactly how far through the storyline you were? Because I too vaguely remember experiencing this...

Comment: Restarting the game solved the problem.